# Error in for loop that runs forever without stopping

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Essentially, my code is set to throw a default amount of darts (10,000) at a dartboard, which will calculate Pi. If no arguments are entered, there will be a default 10,000 darts being thrown If the user enters an argument, that argument will be the number of darts being thrown.

Right now, the program will run the for loop forever, without stopping. I realize that since my porgram isn't stopping, the for loop is not ending. It's an error with how I write the second conditional in the for loop, and how I intialize the numberOfDarts variable above, but I'm not sure what to do.

```
public class PiEstimator {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  int numberOfThrows = 0;

  if (args.length == 0) {

  numberOfThrows = 10000;      

}

if (args.length > 0) {

  numberOfThrows = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

}

if (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) < 0) {
  System.out.println("Cannot throw a negative amount of darts");

}

int numberOfHits = 0;

System.out.println("start");
```

And the for loop is written like this (The loop itself works fine, I believe the error is within the conditions.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThrows; i++) {

  double x = Math.random();
  double y = Math.random();

  numberOfThrows++;

  if (x*x + y*y <= 1) {
    numberOfHits++;
      System.out.println(x + " " + y + " in");
    }

  if (x*x + y*y > 1) {
      System.out.println(x + " " + y + " out");
    }

}

System.out.println("end");
System.out.println("Darts : " + numberOfThrows + " " + "Hits : " + numberOfHits + " " + "Pi Estimation : " + (4*((double)numberOfHits/(double)numberOfThrows)));
```

}

}

Comment: There's nothing wrong with those conditions. The bug must be in the code you didn't show (the body of the loop)

Comment: I guess your value of `numberofThrows` is negative. You print a message in that case but still allow to enter the loop

Comment: @user7 if `numberofThrows` were negative then presumably `i` would not be less than `numberofThrows`. The loop would terminate immediately.

Comment: Just added the rest of the program (The entire for loop and the rest of the method.)

Comment: Your issue is `numberOfThrows++`.  `numberOfThrows` grows as quickly as `i` so the loop never exits. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oh.. Yeah..

Answer (score 3):

Remove this

```
numberOfThrows++;
```

Otherwise the loop won't terminate, since the stopping condition is `i < numberOfThrows`, so if `numberOfThrows` keeps growing, `i` will never pass it (at least until `numberOfThrows` overflows and becomes negative).

In addition, change your conditions to :

```
int numberOfThrows = 0;
if (args.length == 0) {
  numberOfThrows = 10000;      
}
if (args.length > 0) {
  numberOfThrows = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  if (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) < 0) {
    System.out.println("Cannot throw a negative amount of darts"); 
  }
}
```

You only want to check for a negative input when you know there is an input.

Comment: It works perfectly with an added argument! However when there is no argument (When I want it to default to 10,000), the error still appears.

Comment: @etree Works fine for me.

Comment: If I comment out line 19, the one that says if the argument value is less than 0 "A negative amount of darts can't be thrown line." Yes it works, but when I include it in the code, the error pops up if I have no arguments.

Comment: Ohh I see, so simply the second if statement is placed inside the first one?

Comment: @etree yes, since if args.length == 0, you can't access `args[0]`

Comment: And one last question, how would I get the program to avoid running the other print lines if the value is a negative number. My "Cannot throw a negative amount of darts" work correctly, but "start" "end" and the final print line still appear.

Comment: @etree You can either throw an exception when the input is negative, or wrap the code that follows the conditions with `if (numberOfThrows > 0) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are increasing `numberOfThrows` on every iteration of loop which causes the loop to be infinite.So suppose if

```
numberOfThrows=1
for (int i = 0; i <numberOfThrows ; i++) {
  numberOfThrows++
  numberOfThrows++  // if the if condition is also true

//next iteration loop would be
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  // and increases for other iteration causing it infinite
```

Answer (score 1):

You are increasing the number of throws here:

numberOfThrows++;

The loop never ends because it goes from 0 to `numberOfThrows`, which keeps increasing. Remove this line and it will work fine.